# PHP GC and mysqli_free_result

Tags: php, memory, mysqli, garbage-collection

This is not a real issue, nor a duplicate of "mysqli_free_result" questions.
So, let's consider the PHP following code snippet:

```
function foo() {
 $x = mysqli_connect(...);
 $query = 'SELECT id FROM employers WHERE <<condition>> LIMIT 1;';
 $result = mysqli_query($x, $query);
 $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
 return $row["id"];
}
```

I am perfectly aware of the recommendations about `mysqli_free_result`. I am not asking for them.
The same question could be rephrased for calling `mysqli_close` in the same scenario.

So, my question is, would `$result` be ever garbage collected when it gets out of scope (i.e. when function `foo` returns) ?

Comment: Once you return from a function, everything that exists ONLY in the scope of that function is a candidate for garbage collection. Of course it would only be collected if/when memory became an issue

Comment: Thanks for that fast comment @RiggsFolly. Assuming it would only be collected if memory is an issue, it means that the underlying mysql connection - let it be a TCP one to a remote database server - will still be alive until GC kicks in ?

Comment: Well I was going to add that you should not connect in a function. Connect in the main body of code and pass the connection around to functions as a parameter. The connection process is a comparatively slow one

Comment: There is a thing called *destructor*. So - no, it don't have to wait until GC.